# Google Chrome Extension: highlight the div that the mouse is hovering over

Tags: google-chrome-extension, onhover

I am new to Google Chrome extensions and trying to write an extension that highlights a `div` on hover. If there is a `div` inside another `div` and inner `div` is hovered, I would like to highlight the internal `div` only.

I have got some of the samples working but I'm not sure how to catch the hover event.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In HTML, every mouse event has access to the underlying element. You can do that easily with JavaScript, and there is a nice feature in HTML5 called [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) (thanks to Erik from Chromium) that allows you to add and remove classes from DOM's easily.

First of all, you can achieve this with Google Chrome's [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). The algorithm is quite straightforward, you keep a pointer to the last visited DOM, and you just add/remove class's when you visit another DIV element.

Within your **manifest.json** We will define the CSS and JS injections to every page we see.

```
 ...
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "css": ["core.css"],
      "js": ["core.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
  ...
  ...
```

Now lets look into our **core.js**, I have included some comments to explain what is going on:

```
// Unique ID for the className.
var MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME = 'crx_mouse_visited';

// Previous dom, that we want to track, so we can remove the previous styling.
var prevDOM = null;

// Mouse listener for any move event on the current document.
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var srcElement = e.srcElement;

  // Lets check if our underlying element is a DIV.
  if (srcElement.nodeName == 'DIV') {

    // For NPE checking, we check safely. We need to remove the class name
    // Since we will be styling the new one after.
    if (prevDOM != null) {
      prevDOM.classList.remove(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);
    }

    // Add a visited class name to the element. So we can style it.
    srcElement.classList.add(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);

    // The current element is now the previous. So we can remove the class
    // during the next iteration.
    prevDOM = srcElement;
  }
}, false);
```

Now, lets look at the simple **core.css** for the styles:

```
.crx_mouse_visited {
  background-color: #bcd5eb !important;
  outline: 1px solid #5166bb !important;
}
```

Thats it, you will notice that all your divs will have a "hovered" state, similar on what happens when you visit your browser inspector when inspecting elements.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, your answer helped me allot. Please see my improvements bellow.

Answer (score 9):

Now it is 2018, and 7.5 years past since this question was asked.
Yet the question is still relevant, and the answer provided by [mohamed-mansour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130515/mohamed-mansour) is the best.

Yet I wish to optimize it a bit, modernize with support for https, and provide full documentation to the whole Chrome extension.

### mannifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Mark active image",
    "version": "1.11",
    "description": "Mark image with dashed frame.",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "declarativeContent"
    ],
     "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "css": [
                "imageMarker.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "imageMarker.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

### imageMarker.js

In my example bellow I am marking images (IMG tag) in the page with dashed outline. And avoid redundant processing on the current image.

```
// Unique ID for the className.
var MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME = 'crx_mouse_visited';

// Previous dom, that we want to track, so we can remove the previous styling.
var prevDOM = null;

// Mouse listener for any move event on the current document.
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    let srcElement = e.srcElement;

    // Lets check if our underlying element is a IMG.
    if (prevDOM != srcElement && srcElement.nodeName == 'IMG') {

        // For NPE checking, we check safely. We need to remove the class name
        // Since we will be styling the new one after.
        if (prevDOM != null) {
            prevDOM.classList.remove(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);
        }

        // Add a visited class name to the element. So we can style it.
        srcElement.classList.add(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);

        // The current element is now the previous. So we can remove the class
        // during the next ieration.
        prevDOM = srcElement;
        console.info(srcElement.currentSrc);
        console.dir(srcElement);
    }
}, false);
```

### imageMarker.css

```
.crx_mouse_visited {
    background-clip: #bcd5eb!important;
    outline: 1px dashed #e9af6e!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@pdknsk What you can do to set this for every element is, for the `onload` event of the body, run this code:

```
bod= document.body;
walker = document.createTreeWalker(bod,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,null,false);
while (walker.nextNode()){
    walker.currentNode.addEventListener("mouseover",on,false);
    walker.currentNode.addEventListener("mouseout",off,false);
}
```

and modify on and off like this:

```
on=function(elem){ oldBG = this.style.backgroundColor;
                   this.style.backgroundColor='#123456';
                   this.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){this.style.backgroundColor= oldBG},false);
}
```

The thing to notice is that, this will only work if the styling is set using the `element.style` object, and in order to make it more robust you will need to get the `element.style.cssText` and process (using regex) and modify it.

All in all, Mohamed Mansour's Answer is the best way to achieve this.